# How can I push the player back on collision in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am wondering how it is possible to make a game object push a player backwards in unity3D. I am talking about on collision, the game object moving the relative position of the player game object. I know that part of this could be done using the physics settings. Can someone please elaborate on what I would have to do or what documentation would be useful for this?

Comment: If you use [`PhysicsMaterial`s](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) for your colliders and adjust the bounciness and friction correctly this would happen automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Are Two Solutions
One : you can just use unity [PhysicsMaterail](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html)
Two : this is custom code i made that can help you (befor i start there is great video by SebastianLague about [trigonometry](http://youtube.com/watch?v=-dGi2Ffdiuk) that explains how i get the push direction)

```
//the rigidbody of your object
Rigidbody rb = GetCommponent<Rigidbody>();
//calculating the direction where we should push our object
Vector3 direction =  new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad(90 - transfrom.eulerAngles.z)),Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad(90 - transform.eulerAngles.z)),Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad(90 - transform.eulerAngles.y))) * - 1;
```

then you apply force to the player

```
rb.addForce(direction * pushingForce);
```

Update :
there is third one and i think it' the simplest one .
you can just use :

```
rb.addForce(transform.backwards * pushingForce)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html
Or rigidbody.addforce in code

Answer (score 1):

check out effectors in youtube , i think it might help you good luck